# Amazon Deequ (Spark + Scala ) - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.Option org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateFunction.toAgg

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-deequ

**Spark Version** - 3.0.1
**Amazon Deequ version** - deequ-2.0.0-spark-3.1.jar

**Im running the below code in spark shell in my local :**

```
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.{AnalysisRunner, AnalyzerContext}   
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalyzerContext.successMetricsAsDataFrame  
import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.{Compliance, Correlation, Size, Completeness, Mean, 
ApproxCountDistinct, Maximum, Minimum, Entropy}  

import com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.{Compliance, Correlation, Size, Completeness, Mean, 
ApproxCountDistinct, Maximum, Minimum, Entropy}

val analysisResult: AnalyzerContext = {AnalysisRunner.onData(datasourcedf).addAnalyzer(Size()).addAnalyzer(Completeness("customerNumber")).addAnalyzer(ApproxCountDistinct("customerNumber")).addAnalyzer(Minimum("creditLimit")).addAnalyzer(Mean("creditLimit")).addAnalyzer(Maximum("creditLimit")).addAnalyzer(Entropy("creditLimit")).**run()**}
```

**ERROR:**

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.Option 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateFunction.toAggregateExpression$default$2()'
at org.apache.spark.sql.DeequFunctions$.withAggregateFunction(DeequFunctions.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DeequFunctions$.stateful_approx_count_distinct(DeequFunctions.scala:60)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.ApproxCountDistinct.aggregationFunctions(ApproxCountDistinct.scala:52)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunner$.$anonfun$runScanningAnalyzers$3(AnalysisRunner.scala:319)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunner$.liftedTree1$1(AnalysisRunner.scala:319)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunner$.runScanningAnalyzers(AnalysisRunner.scala:318)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunner$.doAnalysisRun(AnalysisRunner.scala:167)
at com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunBuilder.run(AnalysisRunBuilder.scala:110)
... 63 elided
```

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Deeque version 2.0.0 with Spark 3.0 because it's binary incompatible due of the changes in the Spark's internals.  With Spark 3.0 you need to use version `1.2.2-spark-3.0`

Comment: Thanks much for the solution, changing the Amazon Deequ version resolved the issue.
Can you please let me know how and where to check the compatible versions for spark/scala and Deequ

Comment: you can use Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.deequ/deequ - Deequ has Spark version as part of the version